# To convert the html to plain text in php

Tags: php

I have an array with these bellow content.

```
<p><span style="color:#000000"><span style="font-family:dejavu sans mono,monospace; font-size:11px">Popularly known as Ideator, among his close circles, Bikash is very passionate about re-engineering out</span><span style="font-family:dejavu sans mono,monospace; font-size:11px">-</span><span style="font-family:dejavu sans mono,monospace; font-size:11px">of-box ideas.</span></span><span style="color:rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family:dejavu sans mono,monospace; font-size:11px"> He loves travelling, reading, and is always up for a business processing challenge for innovative ideas.Loves getting hands dirty with real on-ground work.</span></p>
```

I have to convert the above to plain text like

```
 "Popularly known as Ideator, among his close circles, Bikash is very passionate about re-engineering out of-box ideas.He loves travelling, reading, and is always up for a business processing challenge for innovative ideas.Loves getting hands dirty with real on-ground work."
```

Is there any way to convert the above to plain text in  php.

Comment: use: html_entity_decode( strip_tags( $my_html_code ) );

Answer (score 0):

Try using [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/strip_tags)

e.g.

```
$str = "<p>some test</p>";
$str = strip_tags($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

**[strip_tags](http://www.php.net/strip_tags)**

(PHP 4, PHP 5)

> strip_tags — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

[WORKING DEMO](http://codepad.org/jN1PsrLG)

```
 <?php

    echo strip_tags('<p><span style="color:#000000"><span style="font-family:dejavu sans mono,monospace; font-size:11px">Popularly known as Ideator, among his close circles, Bikash is very passionate about re-engineering out</span><span style="font-family:dejavu sans mono,monospace; font-size:11px">-</span><span style="font-family:dejavu sans mono,monospace; font-size:11px">of-box ideas.</span></span><span style="color:rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family:dejavu sans mono,monospace; font-size:11px"> He loves travelling, reading, and is always up for a business processing challenge for innovative ideas.Loves getting hands dirty with real on-ground work.</span></p>');

    ?>
```

**OUTPUT**

> Popularly known as Ideator, among his close circles, Bikash is very
>   passionate about re-engineering out-of-box ideas. He loves travelling,
>   reading, and is always up for a business processing challenge for
>   innovative ideas.Loves getting hands dirty with real on-ground work.

Answer (score 0):

Regex of some variation should help. I suggest using an [online regex tester](http://regex101.com/) to get the right matching combo first and then deploying it in php after.

try this:

```
$string = '<p><span style="color:#000000"><span style="font-family:dejavu sans mono,monospace; font-size:11px">Popularly known as Ideator, among his close circles, Bikash is very passionate about re-engineering out</span><span style="font-fa...';

$result = preg_replace('/<([\s\S]*?)>/', '', $string);

echo $result;
```